# Doctrine/Symfony2 OneToMany foreign_id saving as NULL

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a relationship from Assembly to ComponentSlot. It is a OneToMany relationship.

```
// Assembly

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ComponentSlot", mappedBy="assembly", cascade={"persist"})
 * @Assert\Valid
 */
protected $componentSlots;

// ComponentSlot

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Assembly", inversedBy="componentSlots")
 */
protected $assembly;
```

The schema this has generated in the database is absolutely fine. Correct columns, correct indices and relations.

The Symfony2 form AssemblyType has a collection of ComponentSlotType. I am able to add multiple ComponentSlot children. On persisting, the Assembly and ComponentSlot children are all saved perfectly well, except that assembly_id is NULL in the component slot table.

I have copied the setup I had on a previous project that saved the relationships just fine, I am completely stumped. The cascade persist is set on the componentSlots fields of Assembly and my past experience with OneToMany is that I do not have to do anything special here, it should be taken care of.

Any pointers would be appreciated :)

Comment: How do you establish the relationship? What methods do you call?

Comment: As I say, I have a project that already functions with OneToMany relationships set up in the same (clearly not ;)) way. In that project the parent has `addLink(Link $link)` and it only calls `$this->link[] = $link`. Indeed, the documentation at http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine.html confirms that linking of the parent and the child collection items is automatic.  This should be automatic, my previous project, the documentation, and the fact that doctrine:generate:entities does not establish that relationship in the auto-generate add method suggest my model is ok and something else awry

Comment: I thought I had it almost - by_reference in the collection form field was omitted rather than being set to false. This did not alter the ID being stored for children though.

Answer (score 4):

Check your previous setup.  I suspect you had something like:

```
// Assembly
public function addComponentSlot($componentSlot)
{
    $this->componentSlots[] = $componentSlot;

    $componentSlot->setAssembly($this);  // Probably left this out when you copied?
}
```

Comment: No, adding this does not change anything. I also tried this on `setComponentSlots` which Symfony2 uses on request->bindRequest to set the objects up and that does not work either.